# Can't change/establish root binding of: [some-def] with set in Clojure

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, lisp, clojurescript

I could not set my dynamic var's value to new one.

```
(def *pop* true)

(set! *pop* false)

=> IllegalStateException Can't change/establish root binding of: *pop* with set  clojure.lang.Var.set (Var.java:221)
```

Also I've added `^:dynamic`, which did not work either.

```
(def ^:dynamic *pop* true)

(set! *pop* false)

=> IllegalStateException Can't change/establish root binding of: *pop* with set  clojure.lang.Var.set (Var.java:221)
```

But on the other hand this code works,(clojure core's var -> `*warn-on-reflection*`)

```
(set! *warn-on-reflection* true)
=> true

*warn-on-reflection*
=> true

(set! *warn-on-reflection* false)
=> false

*warn-on-reflection*
=> false
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Dynamic vars can only be `set!` inside a `binding` scope. So just calling `set!` on `*pop*` won't work - you need to be in the runtime dynamic scope of a binding somewhere in the call stack above.

```
(def ^:dynamic *pop* true)
(binding [*pop* *pop*]  ;; defaulted to the root binding value
  (set! *pop* false)    ;; ok, because in dynamic binding scope
  (println *pop*))      ;; prints "false" (inside per-thread dynamic binding)
(println *pop*)         ;; prints "true" (root value)
```

Note that the "dynamic scope" part of it means that within `binding` you can make arbitrary nested calls and still have access to set and read the per-thread value of `*pop*`.

Regarding `*warn-on-reflection*`, this looks like special behavior but it's actually exactly the same, except hidden from view. The REPL itself creates a dynamic binding scope around the eval of each REPL statement with bindings for a hard-coded set of dynamic vars, of which `*warn-on-reflection*` is one. You can find that set of bindings [here](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.8.0/src/clj/clojure/main.clj#L71-L87).

Answer (score 6):

You can use [alter-var-root](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/alter-var-root) to change the root vars.

```
user=> (def *pop* true)
Warning: *pop* not declared dynamic ...
#'user/*pop*

user=> (alter-var-root #'*pop* (constantly false))
false

user=> *pop*
false
```